# jquery datepicker always above input also after scrolling

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm getting crazy! There are a lot of sollutions but notting is working!
Why is mij datepicker changing position after scrolling in IE? I want it to be sticked to the top-left of my input field, also if the page is scrolled...

Comment: https://www.huurhulp.nl/wijzigen/wijzigen.php?wijzigen_adv=7&code=137292156450fdb329804e526994ad54

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find it out myself after a few our/days!
Put this in beforeshow:

```
function legen_array(input, inst) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        inst.dpDiv.position({
               my: 'left bottom',
               at: 'left top',
               collision: 'none',
               of: input
       });
        }, 1);
)};
```